# Run python script whit QProcess and show into textEdit the result in realtime

Tags: python, pyqt, qprocess, qplaintextedit

I wolud print the result during my script run via
Qprocess but nothing happen.
I thinking I wrote wrong the args into process start but im not sure. Some one has an idea?
Below my code

```
class TotalopenstationDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, FORM_CLASS):    

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        """Constructor."""
        super(TotalopenstationDialog, self).__init__(parent)        
        self.setupUi(self)

    def dataReady(self):
        cursor = self.textEdit.textCursor()
        cursor.movePosition(cursor.End)
        cursor.insertText(str(self.process.readAll()))
        self.textEdit.ensureCursorVisible()

    def callProgram(self):
        # run the process
        # `start` takes the exec and a list of arguments
        python_path = sys.exec_prefix
        python_version = sys.version[:3]
        p = '{}\python'.format(python_path)
        b=QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath().replace("/","\\")#this one works for windows path
        cmd = os.path.join(os.sep, b, 'python', 'plugins', 'totalopenstationToQgis', 
        'scripts', 'totalopenstation-cli-parser.py')        
        self.process = QProcess(self)
        # QProcess emits `readyRead` when there is data to be read
        self.process.readyRead.connect(self.dataReady)        
        self.process.start(p, [cmd, '-i',str(self.lineEdit_input.text()),'-o',str(self.lineEdit_output.text()),'-f',self.comboBox_format.currentText(),'-t',self.comboBox_format2.currentText(),'--overwrite'])

    def on_pushButton_connect_pressed(self):
        self.callProgram()
```

Comment: Can you print the full command line that would be used for the process? `print(self.process.program(), self.process.arguments())` Also: 1. `text()` of QLineEdit is already a string, no need for `str()`; 2. if you want a string from a QByteArray, you must specify the encoding: `cursor.insertText(str(self.process.readAll(), 'utf-8'))`; 3. connect to the [`errorOccurred`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#errorOccurred) signal and print the possible [`error()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#error).

Comment: Thanks for the replay. I don't want print the full commandline bit what happen when the commandline run like in the terminal. About QlineEdit I know it is already a string but in Windows I need write for str() for the white space. But you right I need connect to the errorOccured

Comment: I don't understand what you mean about the command line: we (including you) need to read how the command line looks like, without it it's more difficult to check for errors. I also don't understand your reference to windows: doing `str(lineEdit.text())` is useless, because it's already a string, if with "white space" you're referring to the spacing between commands, that's irrelevant, since the arguments are already "separated" in the list, and QProcess know how to use them. If in your line edits you're inserting *multiple* arguments, then the problem is there: every argument *must* be a ->

Comment: -> separate element of the list, so you need to parse the content of the line edit, ensure that it doesn't contain quoted variables (which, instead, must be in a single element), and then *extend* the argument list. If you've Qt5.15, you can use [`splitCommand`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#splitCommand) to automatically split space-separated arguments without risking parsing problems. Finally, if you need to specify a working directory, you must to use [`setWorkingDirectory()`](://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#setWorkingDirectory)

Comment: I have printed the error and is this : "bound PYQT_SIGNAL errorOccurred of QProcess object at 0x0000029525B8E558" but i can't understand  the problem

Comment: Can you please [edit] your post and update it with the current code?